# Align small circles on big circle at same distance

Tags: geometry

Consider we have a circle with radius $R$ positioned on $O (0, 0)$.

Having $n$ small circles, what's the easiest method to get the center points (of the small circles) knowing the $R$ and $n$ values?

For $n = 1$ we have one point: $(0, -R)$ (the top of the circle).

For $n = 2$ we have two points: $(0, -R)$ and $(0, +R)$ (the top and the bottom of the circle).

### Example

In principle, by adding lines between the points we should obtain regular poligons ($n >= 3$):

$$n = 1 => point$$
   $$n = 2 => segment$$
   $$n = 3 => equilateral-triangle$$
   $$n = 4 => square$$
   $$n = 5 => pentagon$$
   $$n = 6 => hexagon$$
   $$...$$

I added the following drawing so it's easier to understand (same color circles are equally positioned on the big circle).

> [image]

After knowing the points it's very easy to put there the small circles.

Comment: Aren't negative Y coordinates normally considered to be below the origin? And the radius is the distance from the centre point to the circumference, so R/2 would be halfway between the centre and the circumference.

Comment: I use this in a SVG graph and the positive Y coordinates are on the bottom side. Instead of `R / 2` the correct is `R`. That was a mistake I fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know the direction is a matter of definition which may differ between contexts. That's why I phrased that part as a question.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Do you have any idea what's the easiest way to solve this issue?

Comment: Trigonometry. I'm posting from my phone, and I don't know the latex/mathjax. Unless someone beats me to it, I'll post an answer when I can access the mathjax instructions.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Just post the answer and I or someone else will edit it to look fine. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want degrees or radians?

Comment: @SixthOfFour I'd prefer radians, but I don't have anything agains degrees. But finally I want to have a list with coordinates (`[{x: ..., y: ....}, ...]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P_k = \left(cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)R, sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)R\right)$$

where $P$ is the set of center points of the smaller circles and $k$ is an integer between $0$ and $n-1$.

By using trigonometric identities, the above can be somewhat simplified into
$$P_k = \left(sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)R, -cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)R\right)$$

Comment: @Ionicǎ I just realised, this will actually put the first circle at (R, 0) rather than at (0, -R). I will correct the answer shortly.

Comment: I'm testing it. Ok.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ionicǎ You're welcome. Did you have time to test the edited version?

Comment: I already did, and that's exactly what I was thinking at. They just needed to be rotated with 90deg (PI / 2).