# How do I find the coordinates of 10 points spaced equally on a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, pythagorean-triples

I am not extremely good at math but I am working with computer graphics and I need to find a way to cut a circle equally in to 10 sections. To do this I need to define 10 points on the circle and my basic geometry skills have failed me.

I can so far find the point on the circle using this:
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

Comment: Can it be any points?  Does one point need to be vertically above the center or horizontal from center(can't have both)?

Comment: @turkeyhundt preferably vertically

Comment: Also, is the circle centered on $(0,0)$ and you are looking for 10 ordered pairs of coordinates?

Comment: @wowlolbrommer I am trying to find the points on the circle.

Comment: @wowlolbrommer In the form of x,y.  Like I said in the description this is for computer graphics and every thing on computers are defined by points on a plane.

Comment: @wowlolbrommer Yes, the cordinates

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant $x^2+y^2=r^2$, rather than $x^2\times y^2$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, sorry

Comment: A similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083408/align-small-circles-on-big-circle-at-same-distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using degrees, your points are $$(r\times\cos(36^{\circ}x+18^{\circ}),r\times\sin(36^{\circ}x+18^{\circ}))\\\text{with }x=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$

I don't know the technical way to express this.

What this does is give you the $(x,y)$ coordinates of a radius $r$ long from $(0,0)$ at the angles $\{18^{\circ},54^{\circ},90^{\circ},\dots,342^{\circ}\}$

Comment: Remember to multiply the coordinates by r, if r isn't 1.